# How to detect if a command was provided to the shell prompt

Tags: bash, command-line

I want to write a `PROMPT_COMMAND` that's responsive to whatever was provided to the command prompt immediately previous. For example, to switch between an expansive, informative prompt or simple, compact prompt, like so:

```
mikemol@serenity ~ $ echo hi
hi
$ echo ho
ho
$ echo hum
hum
$
mikemol@serenity ~ $
```

Values only appear to get added to the shell's history if they're not empty, so I can't simply test if the most recent history entry is blank. Running `set | grep some_command` after running `some_command` gives me nothing, so it doesn't appear there's an environment variable containing that information.

I principally use `bash`, but would be curious about POSIX-compatible solutions and other shells.

Comment: No; if you hit `enter` a half dozen times at the prompt, no blank lines are added to the listing that `fc -l` provides.

Comment: That might do it. Will have to wait until Monday to try, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ultimately didn't need `PROMPT_COMMAND` at all. Thanks to Christopher for pointing me in the right direction.

Instead, consider this file, `ps1.prompt`:

```
${__cmdnbary[\#]+$(
    echo '\u@\h: \w' # Your fancy prompt goes here, with all the usual special characters available.
) }${__cmdnbary[\#]=}\$
```

I can then feed this into my `PS1`:

```
PS1=$(cat ps1.prompt)
```

(You don't have to do it this way, but I found it convenient for illustration and editing.)

And so we see:

```
mikemol@zoe:~$ echo hi
hi
mikemol@zoe:~$ echo ho
ho
mikemol@zoe:~$ echo hum
hum
mikemol@zoe:~$ 
mikemol@zoe:~$ PS1=$(cat ps1.prompt)
$ 
mikemol@zoe: ~ $ echo hi
hi
$ echo ho
ho
$ echo hum
hum
$ 
mikemol@zoe: ~ $
```

We're using the array hack [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27473009/495147), but instead of using `bash`'s `${parameter:-word}` parameter substitution, we use `${parameter+word}` so we trigger only on there having been no previous command run.

This requires some explanation, as we're forced to use a double-negative in our logic.

### How `${__cmdnbary[\#]-word}${__cmdnbary[\#]=}` works

In the original array hack demonstration, the construct `${__cmdnbary[\#]-word}${__cmdnbary[\#]=}` was used. (I've replaced `$?` with `word` for clarity). If you're not particularly familiar with parameter expansion and arrays (I wasn't), it's not at all clear what's happening.

#### First, understand `\#`

Per [the manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#index-prompting):

> `\#` the command number of this command

...

> The command number is the position in the sequence of commands executed during the current shell session.

This means `\#` will only change *if and only if* a command is executed. If the user enters a blank line at the prompt, no command is executed, and so `\#` won't change.

#### The setting of an empty string in ${__cmdnbary[#]=}

`${__cmdnbary[\#]=}` uses paramater expansion. Going back to [the manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter:=word}`
>
> **Assign Default Values**. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is assigned to parameter. The value of parameter is then substituted.

So, if `__cmdnbary[\#]` is unset or null, this construct will assign an empty string (`word` is an empty string in our case) and the whole construct will be replaced in our output with that same empty string.

`__cmdnbary[\#]` will *always* be unset or null the first time we see it, since # is monotonic--it always increments or stays the same. (That is, until it loops, likely around 2^31 or 2^63, but there are other problems we'll have *long* before we get there. There's a reason I describe the solution as a bit of a hack.)

#### The conditional in `${__cmdnbary[\#]-word}`

`${__cmdnbary[\#]-word}` is another parameter expansion. From the manual:

> `${parameter:-word}`
>
> **Use Default Values**. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

So, if the array entry at `\#` is *unset or null*, `word` gets used in its place. Since we don't try to assign to `__cmdnbary[\#]` (using the `${parameter:=word}` substitution) until after we check it, the first time we check it for a given `\#` should find that position in the array unset.

#### `bash` uses sparse arrays

One point of clarification for those accustomed to C-style arrays. `bash` actually uses *sparse arrays*; until you assign *something* to a position in an array, that position is unset. An empty string is not the same thing as "null or unset".

### Why we use ${__cmdnbary[#]+word}${__cmdnbary[#]=} instead

`${__cmdnbary[\#]+word}${__cmdnbary[\#]=}` and ${__cmdnbary[#]-word}${__cmdnbary[#]=}`look very siilar. The *only* thing we change between the two constructs can be found in the first portion; we use`${parameter:+word}`instead of`${parameter:-word}`.

Remember that with `${parameter:-word}`, `word` gets presented only if `parameter` is null or unset--in our case, only if we *haven't* set the position in the array yet, which we won't have done if and only if `\#` has incremented, which will only happen if we've just executed a command.

That means that, with `${parameter:-word}`, we'll only present `word` if we *haven't* executed a command, which is precisely the opposite of what we want to do. So, we use `${parameter:-word}` instead. Again, from the manual:

> `${parameter:+word}`
>
> **Use Alternate Value**. If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.

Which is (unfortunately), more double-negative logic to understand, but there you are.

### The prompt itself

We've explained the switching mechanism, but what about the prompt itself?

Here, I use `$( ... )` to contain the meat of the prompt. Primarily for my own benefit for readability; you don't have to do it that way. You can replace `$( ... )` with whatever you might normally stuff in a variable assignment.

### Why is it a hack?

Remember how we're adding entries to a sparse array? We're not removing those entries, and so the array will forever grow until the shell session is exited; the shell is leaking through `PS1`. And so far as I know, there's no way to *unset* a variable or array position in the prompt. You could try in `$()`, but you'll find it won't work; changes made to the variable namespace inside a subshell won't be applied to the space the subshell was forked from.

You *might* try using `mktmp` early in your `.bashrc`, before `PS1` assignment, and stuff information in the resulting file; then you could compare your current `\#` against what you've stored in there, but now you've made your prompt dependent on disk I/O, which is a good way to lock yourself out in emergency situations.